# Why renderscript sample code doesn't work on emulator?(Android)

Tags: android

I have tried to run the sample code of renderscript on emulator but it is not working I want to know can we run the renderscript sample on emualtor ? If not then why.

Answer (score 2):

this needs OpenGL ES 2.0, which is hardware accelerated. So emulator wont support this. Unless google comes up with a emulator version that uses host m/c gles 2.0 to render.